# event listener or onInput command Internet explorer restricted ActiveX controls or scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

```
(function addCastVoteListeners() {
  const els = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.castVote'));
  els.forEach(addCastVoteListener);
})();
function addCastVoteListener(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', castVote);
}
function castVote() {
  console.log(this.id);
}
```

Hi so whenever I run my code I get restricted active X controls click to allow this content. Is there a way for me to program it so that it automatically allows x control without having to click allow. I'm asking because sometime the popup shows up sometime it does not so if it automatically allows it I don't have to worry about me or others clicking on it. I am aware that I could fix this by configuring some of my I.E setting. But I want it so that if someone else goes on the website they do not have to click on it it just allows it for them. Ran on server the Popup doesn't appear but now the event listener is not working. I did not include the full js cause it's really long. But basically the javascript makes a new table(text input) appear/disappaer after user enters a input

```
 // javascript part above html below
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
    <input id = "input1" list="table1"  class="castVote"
    style="width: 500px;"/> 
</label>
<datalist id="table1">
    <option value="Firefox">      
    <option value="more options">
</datalist>
<label>Choose a browser from this list:
    <input id = "input2" list="table2" class="castVote"
    style="width: 500px;"/> 
</label>
<datalist id="table1">
    <option value="safari">      
    <option value="more options 2">
</datalist>

<label>Choose a browser from this list:
    <input id = "inputn" list="tablen" class="castVote"
    style="width: 500px;"/> 
</label>
<datalist id="table1">
    <option value="chrome">      
    <option value="more options n">
</datalist>
```

Comment: unclear how any of that would use ActiveX, my guess is there is something else on your page.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the IE browser displays the IE ActivX warning for security reasons, and there is no way to enable it via JavaScript, except changing [manually Internet Explorer settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17469/windows-internet-explorer-use-activex-controls).

Besides, the provided code doesn't contain the related code about Activex control, please check your code, and then, post the related code to reproduce the problem. You could also check which action will cause the ActiveX prompt? Might be you could find an alternative method to achieve the same action (without using the ActiveX control).

Comment: I think the active X prompt is the onClick,onChange, onInput. I remove it and I no longer get the methods. But I need those to make my code work

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).Because, I have tested your provided code, it will not show the ActiveX prompt.